# Plotting in C# using mathematica

Tags: c#, plot, wolfram-mathematica

Please help me in plotting data that is send from C# to mathematica kernel.
I want to write mathematica code from C# and plot spectroscopic data. 
I have added the necessary assembly and references, I think. My C# code is below.

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
       double baseline;
       int indexOfPeak;
       int minimumIndicesBetweenPeaks;
       int numberOfPixels; 
       double[] spectrum;
       int startingIndex;
       if (spectrometerIndex == -1)
          return; 
       numberOfPixels = wrapper.getNumberOfPixels(spectrometerIndex);
       wrapper.setIntegrationTime(spectrometerIndex, 500000);
       wrapper.setBoxcarWidth(spectrometerIndex, 10);
       wrapper.setCorrectForElectricalDark(spectrometerIndex, 1);
       spectrum = (double[])wrapper.getSpectrum(spectrometerIndex);
       for (int index = 0; index < numberOfPixels; ++index)
       {
           listBox2.Items.Add("pixel[" + index + "] = " +
           spectrum[index]);               
       }
       MathKernel mathKernel = new MathKernel();
       mathkernel.ListPlot[spectrum];
    }            
}
```

Comment: With that extra bracket I suspect it does'nt even compile.

Comment: Also, I don't know wolfram mathematica, but I doubt ListPlot is an array. I think you should learn C# before attempting to use advanced libraries. You also declare a wall of uninitialized variables at function start, this goes against the concept of scoping and resource management. Indentation should be improved. Where is `spectrometerIndex` from?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of methods, based on a post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27956/363)

You may need to format your `spectrum` data suitably for Mathematica, e.g.

```
string data = "1.234, 2.345, 3.456";
```

For GIF format

```
MathKernel mathKernel = new MathKernel();
mathKernel.CaptureGraphics = true;
mathKernel.GraphicsFormat = "GIF";
mathKernel.Compute("Show[ListPlot[{" + data + "}]]");
mathKernel.Graphics[0].Save("C:\\Temp\\plot.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

For enhanced metafile (scalable graphics)

```
MathKernel mathKernel  = new MathKernel();
mathKernel.Compute("ExportString[ListPlot[{" + data + "}], {\"Base64\", \"EMF\"}]");
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(mathKernel.Result.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\plot.emf", decodedBytes);
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Many thanks for your response. I am unfamiliar with C# and Mathematica and doing this for scientific data acquire. I have tried, I am not able to plot the spectrum in Windows Forms. In mathkernel object, Graphics property is not having any value. While running, is showing exception - "Index was outside the bounds of the array".